# Ionic - Show popups on different instance of same component at same time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to show a popup, like alert or popover, for multiple instances of a page component in same page at same time, like following image.

What about a good way to do that? Is there a right ionic component?

[image: enter ionic popup on multiple instance of page component]

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances of a page component in same page at same time" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using Modal Controller. Here are some hints:

```
import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class HomePage {

 constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

 }

 presentProfileModal() {
   let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { userId: 8675309 });
   profileModal.present();
 }

}

@Component(...)
class Profile {

 constructor(params: NavParams) {
   console.log('UserId', params.get('userId'));
 }

}
```

In profile-page.scss file:

```
page-profile {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  background-color: rgba(217, 222, 230, 0.74);
  ion-content {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .scroll-content {
        display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Official doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/